# How do I set a stable ip in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip-address, firewall, static-ip-address, dynamic-ip

I set up a cloud instance with Google Cloud Engine; It works well: I can SSH into it and I can use a VNC client in any desktop to connect to it.

However, that causes a lot of trouble. I set the approved addresses as 0.0.0.0/0. This works, but it also leaves my account vulnerable. Even though hackers don't succed to break through, their attempts makes my vnc server to reject new attempts, including mine.

How about changing the approved ip addresses to only my own? The problem with that is that I use an internet provider that constantly changes my ip - it can change multiple times in 5 minutes. As a result, I have to change the approved ip all the time.

I have set up a static ip for my laptop, but the ip that my vnc server sees is the ip set by my internet service provider.
Is there a way to ask GCE to only check the computer's ip?
Is there a way to set my external ip to a static one (without contacting my ISP)?

Is there anything I can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAP for [TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding).

This way your VM doesn't need a Public IP (So it's not exposed to the internet) and IAP for TCP forwarding supports both SSH and RDP

Comment: Can I use a VNC client after I remove my external ip? I can't find a way to connect with a VNC client without an external ip. I don't just want to connect with SSH, I want to use my VNC client safely too.

Comment: Yes you can, configure IAP according to the doc i linked above and than you can start a local tunnel with gcloud like this (replace instance_name with the name of your VM)

gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel Instance_name 5901 \
--local-host-port=localhost:5901

And in your VNC client use localhost:5901

Here is an article with more details https://medium.com/google-cloud/connecting-securely-to-google-compute-engine-vms-without-a-public-ip-or-vpn-720e53d1978e